# How to use variables from different class in swift?

Tags: swift, variables

I want to access a variable from my AppDelegate Class in my other class

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate

class Other: NSView
```

I tried AppDelegate.variable but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this: `let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate` and then you can access its member variables.

Comment: don't forget to add `import UIKit`

Comment: It says no such module UIKit... Maybe because is a mac app I don't know